# Any free extensions for Single Sign-on using Shibboleth or ActiveDirectory?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, extensions, login

I have a simple question - are there any free extensions for Joomla 2.5.x or 3.x that can incorporate Single sign-on using a Shibboleth in Joomla? I can even consider ActiveDirectory as a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the one I'm aware of is [JMapMyLDAP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/18108), it supports SSO with HTTP for LDAP directories and has support for OpenLDAP as well as commercial solutions such as Microsoft Active Directory and Novell eDirectory.

Have you tried that one? Otherwise have you looked in the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/)'s section on "[Authentication - Cloud Based](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based)"?

Comment: Yup, I did try that one. I think it might work, but I am waiting till tomorrow, after memorial day, to work with the IT staff here to figure out how to configure it. Once I do that I can see if it works as it should for my site. Will let you know if it doesn't.

Comment: While your suggestion was good I have trouble setting up the plugin as I need assistance from the IT folk at my university. However, I am happy to note that I solved the issues with the plugin I was working with before (externallogin). Thanks, may be some other day I can figure how to use a more advanced plugin. But for now, this externallogin is fine.

Comment: Glad you got it working :D

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but not just for Shibboleth, ADFS and for some other Identity Providers too.

Came across this plugin - [Joomla Plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/miniorange-sso-for-joomla/)

It serves my purpose and supports way more IDPs than I even know about.